# Where can I download the latest beta of PlayFramework 2.6 so that I can use it with Scala 2.12?

Tags: scala, playframework

Where can I download the latest beta of PlayFramework 2.6 so that I can use it with Scala 2.12? Is one available? All the links from documentation, e.g. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Highlights26 seem to lead to dead-ends when I actually try to download. If it is not available, should the documentation not at least *state* that? Why no branches or tags corresponding to 2.6 in Github? Why is there a migration guide for 2.6 if it cant' yet be downloaded?

Comment: Play 2.6 is simply not yet released. As you can see at playframework.com latest version is 2.5.10

Comment: how did you get that link? as far as I understand, both the migration guide and the release notes are continuously being updated/created while the development is in progress. since the release for 2.6 is not done yet, the main page doesn not link to those guides yet though. If you want to get the current state of development, your best shot would be the master branch -- however I doubt it's even feature complete.

Comment: I searched google for Play Framework and Scala 2.12 and somehow found it. I think what took me by surprise was seeing what appeared to be live documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try building the framework from source.
The github master branch should contain the latest developments.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/BuildingFromSource

Be careful though, it may be unusable.